# Use jquery date picker on form to convert user input to integer date

Tags: jquery, mysql, date, datepicker

user enters date using the jquery date picker ,this is presented in the format mm/dd/yyyy the form is used to query a MySQL database using a column(CADNO) that records dates in integer format ,e.g. -3987 .

-3987 is is calculated from 05/09/2006(which is the date kepreported_date column) this is because the CADNO column counts how many days from todays date the reported_date column is .

question is ,is there a way to create a formula on the jquery that would convert the user inputted date to a format that the MySQL server is expecting ?

```
<script>
```

$( function() {

```
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",

  date_from = $( "#date_from" )
    .datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on( "change", function() {

      date_to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );

    }),

  date_to = $( "#date_to" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3
  })
  .on( "change", function() {

    date_from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });
function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }
  return date;
}
```

} );

```html
ts=ts&"<form method='post' action='search_prep.asp'>"
ts=ts&"<tr><td>Search</td>"
ts=ts&"<td><select size='1' name='search_field' id='search_field'>"
for p=0 to colrows
 ts=ts&"<option value='"&cols(0,p)&"'>"&cols(1,p)&"</option>"
next
ts=ts&"</select></td></tr>"
ts=ts&"<tr><td>For</td>"
ts=ts&"<td><input type='text' size='12'  name='search_text' id='search_text' >"
ts=ts&"&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='andor' value='and'>AND"
ts=ts&" <input type='radio' name='andor' value='or' "&chkandor&">OR"
ts=ts&"&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' size='12' name='search_text2' id='search_text2'></td>"
ts=ts&"<td><input type='checkbox' name='search2' value='yes' "&chk2stage&"  >2 Stage query required</td>"
ts=ts&"<td>"
ts=ts&"<input type='radio' name='repclr' value='radno' "&chkreprep&">Reports"
ts=ts&" <input type='radio' name='repclr' value='cadno' "&chkrepclr&" >Clears "
'ts=ts&" range between <select size='1' name ='date_from' id='date_from'>" -commented for datepicker
ts=ts&"</tr> "
ts=ts&"</td>"
ts=ts& "<tr><td>Date Between</td> <td><input type='text' style='text-align:center;' size='19' name='date_from' id='date_from'>"
'for i = mindate to maxdate-commented for datepicker
 'ts=ts&"<option value="&i&">"&date() + i&"</option>"-commented for datepicker
'next-commented for datepicker
'ts=ts&"</select>"-commented for datepicker

'ts=ts&"and<select size='1' name ='date_to' id='date_to'>"
'for i = maxdate to mindate step -1
' ts=ts&"<option value="&i&">"&date() + i&"</option>"
'next
'ts=ts&"</select>"
ts=ts& "&nbsp;&nbsp;And&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' style='text-align:center;' size='19' name='date_to' id='date_to'>"
ts=ts&"</td>"
  
ts=ts&"<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='submit' value='Go'></td>"


ts=ts&"</tr> "
ts=ts&"<input type='hidden' name='nocom' value='"&nocom&"'>"
ts=ts&"<input type='hidden' name='current_tech' value='"&current_tech&"'>"
ts=ts&"<input type='hidden' name='current_status' value='"&current_status&"'>"
ts=ts&"<input type='hidden' name='status' value='"&status&"'>"



ts=ts&"</form></table></div>"
```

Comment: Please enter your correct code

Comment: What is ts=ts& ??

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in javascript with the following snippet:

```
var firstDate = new Date(2006,05,09);
var secondDate = new Date(1990,01,01);

function (firstDate, secondDate){
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds

    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    return diffDays;
}
```

It will return the number of days from first date given to the second date given.

Comment: apologies if my question was not clear ,i wanted something similar but instead of finding the difference between the two days i wanted a formula that would use the user inputted date minus todays date ,both independent between the date from and the date to .

Comment: You can pass the firstDay as user input date and secondDate as todays. You'll get your required data.

Comment: is it possible to instead of the diffdays have it create the output of the formula it to a element ID

Comment: Yes, get that function a name and you can do it like this:
$('#yourElementId').html(functionCall(args, args));